# What bytecode will Kotlin compiller produce if jvmToolchain is set to 11 and jvmTarget to 1.8?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jvm-bytecode

I have [a Kotlin project](https://github.com/sol4k/sol4k) that I want to compile to Java 1.8 bytecode so that it could also be used on Android as well. I use the `com.vanniktech.maven.publish` Gradle plugin to publish the library to Maven Central. This plugin works [only when I set jvmToolchain to 11](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin/issues/518). However I can still set `jvmTarget` to 1.8. This way, my configuration would look like this:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}
```

This works, but I am not sure what bytecode it would produce. It also gives compilation warning asking me to set both values to the same version.

**Question:** What version of bytecode will Gradle project produce if  `jvmToolchain` is set to 11 and `jvmTarget`  to 1.8?

Alliteratively, how can I make it produce Java 1.8 bytecode in a different way? (If I am doing something wrong).